# Invoke java from another java process make it halted

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a program with 2 process java : processA and processB ( 2 process java.exe not 2 threads).
i use code block below from process A to invoke processB this code is wrapped in RunTask class below

```
public class RunTask implements Callable<Object> {

private String runParams;

public String getRunParams() {
    return runParams;
}

public void setRunParams(String runParams) {
    this.runParams = runParams;
}

@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    try {
        //System.out.println("run:" + runParams);
        Process procB = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar processB.jar);
        DataInputStream ls_in = new DataInputStream(procB.getInputStream());
        String ls_str;
        while ((ls_str = ls_in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ls_str);
        }

    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

and Main class i use executor

```
   ExecutorService eservice = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        while (1 == 1) {
            String stringParams = getFilesNeedToImportAsString();
            if (stringParams.trim().isEmpty()) {
                long l1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
                System.out.println("all time" + l1 / 1000);
                System.exit(100);
            }
            RunTask runTask = new RunTask();
            runTask.setRunParams(SystemInfo.RUN_COMMAND + stringParams);
            Future<Object> objectFuture = eservice.submit(runTask);
            while (!objectFuture.isDone()) {
                System.out.println("waiting the task running");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }
```

But when an exception occurred on processB both processes (processA,processB) seem be halted this is code run on processB

```
public Object call() {
    try {
        MutationResult result = mutator.execute();
        return "ok";
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("error on " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "failed begin retry " + (++retryCount));
        call();
        System.out.println(retryCount + " completed");
        return "ok";
    }

}
```

if i run processB stand alone (by command line) it's never happen, or when this problem occured i use taskmanager to kill proceesA (callee), processB continue to run

Please any one give me the solution for this problem !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wait on `objectFuture` `isDone` method to complete. According to the documentation:

> isDone: Returns true if this task completed. Completion may be due to
>   normal termination, an exception, or cancellation -- in all of these
>   cases, this method will return true

Looking at the code in processB when an exception occurs you execute `call()` again recursively. I understand that you do this as a error retry mechanism but this is a really bad idea for two main reasons:
- If the exception persists you will end up getting a `StackOverflowException`.
- None of the conditions for `isDone` will be met.

A better alternative will be defining a maximum number of retries and try executing `mutator.execute()`. If the error persists then throw and exception and finish execution.

Another option would be to wait to processB to finish for a maximum time after which you cancel the execution of the task by calling `objectFuture.cancel(true)`.

A couple of comments on processA: On `RunTask` you don't use `runParams` which seem to be some files that need to be imported as string. Also, you use `readLine()` on `DataInputStream` which is a deprecated method. Instead use an `InputStream` (e.g. `BufferedInputStream`) wrapped in an `InputStreamReader` and then wrapped in a `BufferedReader` - then call `readLine()` on the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: thanks spaniard StackOverflowException maybe occur here!! i have fixed it :D :D

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've had trouble with when spawning exec's is that, if an error occurs and I haven't set up a thread to read the ErrorStream, then the ErrorStream buffer can fill up, at which point everything grinds to a halt waiting for me to clear some of the text from the ErrorStream buffer.  Process B can't write any more of the error until I do, and Process A is waiting for Process B to finish.

End result of my experience: Always set up a thread to read each of the InputStream and ErrorStream when you exec().

Answer (score 1):

`printStackTrace` will print to standard error, not standard out.  You will either need to read standard error as well (which is tricky - you will need 2 threads, one for each stream), or print to standard out instead (`printStackTrace(System.out)`).